# Piecewise vector

Tags: list-manipulation, vector, piecewise

I need to have a vector with the length of 15000. The first 4000 elements have value 12, the next 3000 elements, that is 4001 to 7000 be 0 and the rest of it to the last be 5. I have written it with the following:

```
Tl = ConstantArray[0, 15000];
Tl[[1 ;; 4000]] = 12;
Tl[[4001 ;; 7000]] = 0;
Tl[[7001 ;; 15000]] = 5;
```

But I wanna know is there a way to do it with `Table` or `Piecewise` or any other ways except part specification.
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Table[Piecewise[{{12, x <= 4000}, {0, x <= 7000}, {5, True}}], {x, 1, 15000}]
```

The last `True` means some as "otherwise"

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join):

```
r1=Join[
    ConstantArray[12, 4000],
    ConstantArray[0, 3000],
    ConstantArray[5, 8000]
];
```